# how can I list, with lsof command, TCP Established connections ignoring localhost?

Tags: lsof

Using `lsof` command I would like to print out `TCP` connections with `ESTABLISHED` state but ignoring the ones with localhost.

I tried:

```
lsof -itcp@^127.0.0.1 -stcp:established
lsof -itcp@(^127.0.0.1) -stcp:established
lsof -itcp -i ^@127.0.0.1 -stcp:established
```

and others similar, but always getting sintax error response.

What is correct sintax?

Comment: Try using `ss -tlpn -o state ESTABLISHED`  This is much better than `lsof` for what you want.

Comment: Or while at it as a Linux-only method: `ss -4tnp state established not dst 127.0.0.0/8` . @ValentinBajrami btw: `-l` is incompatible with `state established` (because it means `state listening`).

Comment: @A.B on that's so true. Wasn't even thinking since I usually type `ss -tlpen`...   most of the time.  Good pointers and `not dst 127.0.0.0/8` is definitely what's needed here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't look like you can negate network addresses in `lsof`.

If on Linux, you could use `lsfd` from `util-linux` instead:

```
lsfd -Q '(type =~ "^TCP") and
         (name =~ "state=established") and
         (name !~ "addr=(\[::1\]|127)")'
```

Or as mentioned by @A.B `ss` from `iproute2`:

```
ss -tp state established not dst 127.0/8 not dst '[::1]'
```